# Array with key value

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

trying to calculate distance with lat and long and using pre-build php  distance() function.Problem is that I am unable to formet array like this $point1 and $Point 2

```
   $point1 = array("lat" => "48.8666667", "long" => "2.3333333"); // Paris (France)
    $point2 = array("lat" => "19.4341667", "long" => "-99.1386111"); // Mexico City (Mexico)
    echo$km = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);
```

Here is my query and its return array like  this

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 32.9697
                [long] =>  -96.80322
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [lat] => 29.46786
                [long] =>  -98.53506
            )

    )
```

this is code

```
foreach ($usersInfo as $key=> $users)
{
      $ridefrom=$users['ride_from'];
      $rideto=$users['ride_to'];//this is from lat long
      $tempLatLong = explode(',',$users['ride_from']);
       $tempLatLong1 = explode(',',$users['ride_to']);
      $key = array('lat','long');
      $to = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong); 
      $from = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong1);
      $array1=array_push($finalDest,$to);
      $array2=array_push($finalDest,$from);
echo $km = distanceCalculation($array1['lat'], $array1['long'],$array2['lat'],$array2['long']);
print_r($finalDest); // displays all array
}
```

Can I manage this out like $Point1 and $Point2

Thanks

Comment: try to print your `$to` and `$from` array, those should be same as `$point1` and `$point2`. No need to push them in `$finalDest`

Comment: Nitin P@but distance function receive 4 value  so can you correct this plzz

Comment: – Nitin P@update your answer so I can vote you thanks I got my result  according your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already has required arrays, try to print your `$to` and `$from` array, those should be same as `$point1` and `$point2`. No need to push them in `$finalDest`

**Your loop will look like this**

```
    foreach ($usersInfo as $index=> $users){
                      $km= 0;
                      $ridefrom=$users['ride_from'];
                      $rideto=$users['ride_to'];//this is from lat long
                      $tempLatLong = explode(',',$users['ride_from']);
                      $tempLatLong1 = explode(',',$users['ride_to']);
                      $key = array('lat','long');
                      $to = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong); 
                      $from = array_combine($key,$tempLatLong1);
                     $km=distanceCalculation($from['lat'],$from['long'],$to['lat'],$to['long']);
                      $usersInfo[$index]['distance'] = $km;
                 }
```

Comment: Nitin P@you there?

Comment: @newdeveloper : how may I help you

Comment: Nitin P@ $distance=DistanceCalculation($array1['lat'], $array1['long'],$array2['lat'],$array2['long']); @@how can return this value with           return $usersInfo;

Comment: inside your for loop, use `$usersInfo[$key]['distance'] = $distance;`. Also change your array $key to something else, to avoid variable overriding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171780/discussion-between-nitin-p-and-new-developer).